# How to visually represent the distribution of categorical data?

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, visualization

I have a dataset which a column that contains strings which list vegetables e.g. :

| veg |
| --- |
| "carrot,onion,potato" |
| "onion,squash" |
| "onion, pickle" |

I want to visually represent the distribution of each individual vegetable and I'm unsure how to do so, do I use a barchart? Something like:

```
#Get a list of unique values

u_vals = list(set(','.join(df["veg"].dropna()).replace(', ', ',').split(',')))

#Count the number of time each unique value appears in the column and 
#use it to populate a dictionary

cat_list={}

for z in u_vals:
    cat_list.update({z : df[df['veg'].str.contains(z, na=False)].veg.count()})

#Plot a barchart

keys=list(cat_list.keys())
vals=list(cat_list.values())

plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))

ax=sns.barplot(x=keys, y=vals, palette="pastel")
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right")
plt.show
```

Comment: Please add the desired output.

Comment: The question is asking what the desired output should be

Comment: If the question just is *"do I use a barchart?"*, the answer is "yes, that is very suitable".  Note that stackoverflow is meant for problems with code, not for yes-no questions.  How does your plot look like?  What do you need to be different?